# How to iterate two successive elements of the lists of lists in python ?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to iterate two successive  elements of the list of lists.

```
     mentionedlist=[[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4][2,3,4,5][3,4,5,5][1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4][]]
```

Now I want to compare weather first element of a list in mentionedlist and first element of next list in mentionedlist is same, I also want to do these comparision throughout the list.

```
 [1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4] is example of answer that i am expecting.
```

Comment: Do you want `[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]` then `[2,3,4,5][3,4,5,5]` then `[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]`? Or do you want `[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]` then `[1,2,3,4][2,3,4,5]` then `[2,3,4,5][3,4,5,5]`... ?

Comment: I want [1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4] then [2,3,4,5][3,4,5,5] then [1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, to get successive elements:

```
mentionedlist=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,5],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[]]
for l1, l2 in zip(mentionedlist, mentionedlist[1:]):
    print l1, l2
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] [2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5] [3, 4, 5, 5]
[3, 4, 5, 5] [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] []
```

To do pairwise comparison:

```
for l1, l2 in zip(mentionedlist, mentionedlist[1:]):
    if len(l1) == len(l2) and sum(x != y for x,y in zip(l1, l2)) == 0:
        print l1, l2
```

Which gives you:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @NileshAgrawal did you encounter a problem with the method I suggested? (just wondering)

Answer (score 1):

Note: you also need to put commas between the values in your list, i.e `List=[[1,..],[2,..]]`

```
from itertools import islice
mentionedList=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,5],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[]]
for i,v in enumerate(islice(mentionedList,0,len(mentionedList)-1)):
    print (v,mentionedList[i+1])
```

Gives you:

> > > ```
> > > ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
> > > ([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5])
> > > ([2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5])
> > > ([3, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4])
> > > ([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
> > > ([1, 2, 3, 4], [])
> > > ```

With this method you don't need to make a copy of the list.